# GWT Extend Widget Class

Tags: java, gwt, frameworks

As u all know, in GWT we can extend the class of widget for e.g

```
private class CategoryRadio extends RadioButton
    {
        public Category CurrentCategory;
        public CategoryRadio(String name, String label,Category CurrentCategory) 
        {
            super(name, label);
            this.CurrentCategory=CurrentCategory;
        }

    }
```

I need to know whether extending class of widget is possible also in other web development framework. I do not know because gwt is my first web framework, if it would be nice if someone can help??

Comment: "other web development frameworks" is pretty ambiguous. The likely answer is "yes in some, no in others".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are asking about component oriented web frameworks.. 
JSF and Wicket are also component oriented web frameworks.. You could extend or create new UI components by means of these two framework. Well, I do not know about other web framework..

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "extends" is called "Inheritance" in computer science. It is a feature of certain programming languages(object-oriented languages). Gwt is basically Java and since Java offers inheritance it is supported in GWT.

Inheritance should be available in every framework that uses a programming language which has inheritance.

Here is the Wikipedia-Entry on inheritance for further reading: ["Click"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)